# Rasbian on Raspberry Pi trying to run Electron app on startup

Tags: node.js, linux, cron, raspberry-pi, electron

I'm trying to run a script on startup on my Raspberry Pi, I need to ultimatly run `npm run start` after everything has loaded in order to launch my Electron app. If I run this command in the terminal it works just fine, but for hours I've been trying to use a crontab, the RC Local and various other things.

My script doesn't run. I can verify that my rc local file is indeed running and my sh file is running, but Electron is never launched, what am I doing wrong?

- I've got a command to execute a script that runs in `rc.local` which is:

  - `sh '/home/pi/Desktop/cockpit-tv-monitor/start.sh'`
- The contents of `start.sh` is:

```
#!/bin/sh
# start-jammer.sh
# navigate to the home directory, then to this directory, then execute python script, then back home

cd /
cd home/pi/Desktop/cockpit-tv-monitor
echo "about to run npm run start" > /tmp/rc_test.txt
npm run start
```

I am getting the echo, but `npm run start` seems to never launch my electron app, and this command is essentially an alias which runs `electron .`

#### UPDATE 05/05 @ 09:58

I've outputted the contents of `npm run start` to a simple text file using:

- `npm run start >> /tmp/start-output.txt > 2>&1`

The error I'm getting is:

```
> cockpit-tv-monitor@1.0.0 start
> electron .

A JavaScript error occurred in the main process
Uncaught Exception:
Error: Failed to get 'appData' path
    at App.c._setDefaultAppPaths (electron/js2c/browser_init.js:5:1300)
    at Object.<anonymous> (electron/js2c/browser_init.js:197:2129)
    at Object../lib/browser/init.ts (electron/js2c/browser_init.js:197:3540)
    at __webpack_require__ (electron/js2c/browser_init.js:1:128)
    at electron/js2c/browser_init.js:1:1200
    at electron/js2c/browser_init.js:1:1267
    at NativeModule.compileForInternalLoader (internal/bootstrap/loaders.js:283:7)
    at NativeModule.compileForPublicLoader (internal/bootstrap/loaders.js:225:10)
    at loadNativeModule (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:35:9)
    at Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:747:15)
/home/pi/Desktop/cockpit-tv-monitor/node_modules/electron/dist/electron exited with signal SIGSEGV
```

This is even after adding a delay before running `npm run start` of 30s, still get the error.

Comment: Can you get log with `npm run start >> /tmp/rc_test.txt 2>&1` ?

Comment: Can you show us the permissions of `rc.local` and the script you want to run?  Also check the replies on [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9853/how-can-i-make-etc-rc-local-run-on-startup).

Comment: `rc.local` runs on startup, I've verified this by adding some `echos` to output to text files. I thought it could be related to the fact that `rc.local` executes anything straight away, which because it takes time to boot into the OS, `npm run start` can't launch Electron because the GUI, isn't ready yet, a delay though still doesn't work - I'll try outputting the log, but not sure that'll work?

Comment: @Philippe I've outputted the log of the command to a file, and I'm getting an error that consist of `Failed to get 'appData' path` _(refer to my updated description with a more detailed error)_

Comment: Have you set DISPLAY ? you can try `sleep 60; DISPLAY=:0 npm run start`

Comment: @Philippe doesn't seem to have any impact adding a longer sleep and the `DISPLAY` arg

Comment: Once the GUI is up, in one terminal, can you run `env -i DISPLAY=$DISPLAY npm start`, once with user `pi`, and then with user `root` ?

Comment: Instead of the last line, can you write:
cd home/pi/Desktop/cockpit-tv-monitor & npm run start

Answer (score 1):

did you try running it from

```
/home/pi/.xinitrc
```

just create that file, and insert

```
cd /home/pi/Desktop/cockpit-tv-monitor && npm run start &
```

reboot and hope the best.

Comment: If hoping is not enough, use `sudo hope`.  OP has rejected this as a path so it's good to self-delete this answer or demote the answer to a comment under the question.

Answer (score 0):

The error seems to be `Failed to get 'appData' path`, which is probably an OS related thing.

[appData](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/app) is where Electron saves its cookies and other electron runtime related items. This might mean that your OS doesn't have the proper directory that electron can save to.

For linux (e.g. Raspberry Pi), it looks for two things either and environment variable called `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME` or something with this file `~/.config`.

You can output the value of either by

`echo $XDG_CONFIG_HOME`

or

`cat ~/.config`

to see if a paths exist.

If neither work you can update your `npm start` script and pass an environment variable on start like `XDG_CONFIG_HOME="~/usr/electron/myapp" && electron .` that adds the environment variable before boot with a directory.

Comment: This may also be more helpful: https://superuser.com/questions/365847/where-should-the-xdg-config-home-variable-be-defined

Comment: `echo $XDG_CONFIG_HOME` outputs in the terminal: `/home/pi/.config`, which presumably is correct?